# How to convert my phone in silent mode into general mode automatically for specific mobile number

Tags: applications, samsung, settings, security, uploads

If my mobile phone is in silent mode and  I want  my phone automatically converts silent mode to general mode  by getting call from specific number like only for my parents or my friends.
     Many time my phone is in silent mode.If their is emergency call then I want even in silent mode I  get an alert on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

Favourite the contacts that you want to hear their calls from the contacts app. Then go to the settings of do not disturb and change that to priority only. So then only the people you chose  will be able to call you.

Hope this Helps